# Converting Knockout js json to observable

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am struggling to return JSON data and convert it into an observable.  The data is returned fine in JSON format, but it doesn't seem to be assigned to the observable.  Can anybody help?  I am guessing the issue is in the success part of the ajax call :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function StandingsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.standings = ko.observableArray();

    self.DivisionName = ko.observable('');

    self.afceast = ko.computed(function () {

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.standings(), function (i) {
            return "AFC East" == i.DivisionName;
        });
    });

    self.afccentral = ko.computed(function () {

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.standings(), function (i) {
            return "AFC Central" == i.DivisionName;
        });
    });

    self.afcwest = ko.computed(function () {

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.standings(), function (i) {
            return "AFC West" == i.DivisionName;
        });
    });

    self.nfceast = ko.computed(function () {

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.standings(), function (i) {
            return "NFC East" == i.DivisionName;
        });
    });

    self.nfccentral = ko.computed(function () {

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.standings(), function (i) {
            return "NFC Central" == i.DivisionName;
        });
    });

    self.nfcwest = ko.computed(function () {

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.standings(), function (i) {
            return "NFC West" == i.DivisionName;
        });
    });

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/api/standing/GetStandingsBySeason/2018",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            $('#divStandings').html('');
            $('#divStandings').addClass('ajaxRefreshing');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Client', 'jQuery');
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#divStandings').removeClass('ajaxRefreshing');
            self.standings(JSON.parse(result));
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new StandingsViewModel());
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use [Knockout Mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin and map your result to observable.

```
var observableData = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
```

or if your object wasn't parsed automatically by jQuery

```
var observableData = ko.mapping.fromJSON(result);
```

If your data type is array it will be converter to observableArray, so to get it items as normal array you should get like from any other observable by adding brackets;

```
var array = observableData();
```

That array can by assigned to your obsevableArray in that way:

```
self.standings(array);
```

Comment: Didn't get this to work, alert(observableResult) gives this :  function c(){if(0<arguments.length){if(!c.equalityComparer||!c.equalityComparer(d,arguments[0]))c.I(),d=arguments[0],c.H();return this}a.U.La(c);return d}. Do I need any other references?

Comment: What is the result of the `observableResult()`? Are you sure that `result` isn't already parsed?

Comment: alert(observableResult()) gives null

Comment: None of the 3 options above populate self.standings

Comment: An array of [object Object]

Comment: Tried latest suggestion, ko.mapping.fromJSON(result) returns null, ko.mapping.fromJS(result) returns [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] etc

Comment: Note: for ko.toJS(array) to work on older browsers that have no native JSON serializer (e.g., IE 7 or earlier), you must also reference the json2.js library.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option to using the mapping plugin for Knockout would be to use [Knockback](http://kmalakoff.github.com/knockback/). It is a bridge between Knockout and [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/).

You easily get your data like so:

```
//Model
var StandingsModel = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    url:'/api/standing/GetStandingsBySeason/2018' 
});

//View model
var StandingsViewModel = function (standings) {
    this.standings = kb.collectionObservable(standings)
    //...
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    //Get data from server
    var model = new StandingsModel();
    model.fetch( function() {
        success: //...
    });

    //Apply bindings
    ko.applyBindings(new StandingsViewModel(model));
});
```